# Apple Pay crash with on PKPaymentAuthorizationControllerExportedObject authorizationDidFinishWithError

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, applepay, passkit

When I use Apple Pay with Stripe's iOS SDK, it crashes on following method after payment?

```
-[PKPaymentAuthorizationControllerExportedObject authorizationDidFinishWithError:] + 76
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are really just interested to know if others have the same problem as you, instead of finding a solution, the [so] is not the site to post your question. Assuming improper statement of your question I changed it so it is appropriate here.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same crash.  Apple pay would work the first time but on the second try we would get the crash and could reproduce it every time.  The problem is that in the delegate method `didAuthorizePayment` I was doing all the backend processing and when that was successful I was calling the completion block with `completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.Success)` and then dismissing the view controller.

Instead I moved the dismiss code from the `didAuthorizePayment` method to the 'didFinish' method (which required me to hold onto some state to pass to the receipt page).  Once I did that the done button was shown on the apple pay controller and the crashes went away.